# Virus File For Testing AV Software

Tags: anti-virus

I remember running across a few threads that mentioned a file you could download that mimicked the behavior of a true virus. Obviously it is completely harmless and is only used to check the thoroughness of running AV software.

Where can I find this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about the [eicar test file](http://www.eicar.org/85-0-Download.html). It dosn't mimic the behaviour of a virus - its just a text file most AVs detect as a specific virus and delete. Amusingly enough, to avoid annoyance, turn off your AV when creating the eicar file since, some AVs will delete it, silently the MOMENT YOU CREATE IT.

Comment: Note, not all AV programs will detect the eicar test file.

Comment: I had a HELL of a time zipping up a eicar test file for an answer in the past, so my AV detects it ;p. Its also supposed to be the industry standard so it would be unusual that an AV program would not detect it. Any specific one?

Comment: Windows Defender picked up on it as soon as I saved it. It's funny that its just a string of ASCII characters. I'm not sure I understand exactly what this is used for.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ive seen a list out there somewhere... cant find it now.

Comment: Its used to test if your AV works at all. I've used it to [answer this question](http://superuser.com/questions/446303/how-to-share-malicious-source-code/446305#446305) myself. If I had some setup that scanned any USB devices plugged into the computer, it would make a good test. In short, use this anywhere you *wouldn't* want to see a virus, but want to see how a system reacts to an *actual* virus

Comment: @Scandalist AV programs, if they support it, will detect the eicar file as a real virus, however its completely harmless.  If you want to test if your AV is working, this is far safer than using a real virus.